# Typescript optional chaining testing branch count

Tags: typescript, jestjs, babeljs, ts-jest, test-coverage

I'm having some trouble understanding branch coverage when it comes to optional chaining with typescript.

Here is my code

```
type testingType = {
   b?: { a?: number };
};
 
export function example(input: testingType) {
   return input.b?.a;
}
```

Here is the test (just forcing it to pass in order to generate the report)

```
test('test', () => {
   example({});
   expect(1).toBe(1);
});
```

This is the coverage report screenshot (branch coverage 3/4)

[image: coverage report]

I'm trying to wrap my head around why there are 4 branches in total.
Shouldn't there be 2 branches instead?

- `b` defined
- `b` undefined.

Comment: I would guess that is because there is also `a` that can be defined or undefined, so that would make 2 x 2 = 4?

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 branches for this:

```
{b?: { a?: number }}
```

[image: NYC report]

Which are:

- Empty object (`b` undefined): `return input`
- `b` defined, and `a` undefined: `return input.b` (which is `{ b: {} }`)
- `b` defined and a defined: `return input.b.a` which would be `{ b: { a: SOME_NUMBER} }`

Edit:

Here are my test cases:

```
describe('My group', () => {
  test('empty object', () => {
    example({});
    expect(1).toBe(1);
  });

  test('only with b', () => {
    example({ b: {} });
    expect(1).toBe(1);
  });

  test('all keys', () => {
    example({ b: { a: 5 } });
    expect(1).toBe(1);
  });
});
```

Comment: Did you use all 3 cases for that coverage? I only had one test case in the question above. I'm trying to figure out how that one case covered 3 branches though. 

Maybe jest config is messing something up?

Comment: I updated my answer with my test cases

Comment: Yes indeed check your jest, babel and ts config